# Does Apple take apps off the store if they crash a lot

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, crash

I have at least a few iOS apps that tend to crash a lot from the most simple and easy to reproduce functions of the app. I'm curious if any devs have had experience with this, and have found that their apps are eventually removed due to this. I mean, Apple gets tons of crash reports all the time, and surely they'd notice their mistake fairly quickly, and pull the app from the store, right? The question is: Will Apple eventually remove an app that has been crashing on a large number of user's devices, even if it passed review?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've a couple of simple apps in the Mac App Store. When uploading them, Apple thoroughly test the app, from the functionality of the application itself, to whether or not the app quits when the last window open is closed. The same approval process applies to iOS application loading, though I haven't experienced it personally.

The applications that aren't working for you now would have worked when they were released. The most usual issue would be an iOS update crippling the app's functionality, for reasons known to the developer.

Answer (score 0):

I've downloaded apps in the past that completely don't work. I don't think Apple checks them, but if there were enough complaints from customers they would do something about it. However thats not just negative reviews, I mean people going and reporting a problem with it or asking for a refund.